# Posting a nested array in PHP using cURL

Tags: php, json, curl, deserialization

I have some data I need to post to an endpoint which is a nested array like:

```
$contentPostData = array(
            'contents' => array(
                'name' => $comment_text,
                'fingerprint' => $fingerprint,
                'signers' => array(
                    $ownerAuthId
                )
            )
        );
```

When I try:

```
json_encode($contentPostData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

I get the error:

```
string(518) "{"timestamp":1578447151168,"message":"Can't read request","details":["JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
```

How do I format the contentPostData so that it can be deserialized correctly?

Comment: You have your POST data in `$contentPostData`, which you JSON-encode but don't store the result, and then post a completely different variable called `$data`?

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

```php
json_encode($contentPostData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

But are you assigning the encoded json to `$data`? I mean:
are you doing:

```php
$data = json_encode($contentPostData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

I see that the webservice to which you are calling uses `com.fasterxml.jackson` so most likely expects JSON format and therefore your serialization should be okay (if field names and types match).

I also suggest setting the header to inform that webservice that you are sending a json file (in case it allows other formats):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json'                                                                     
);
```

So:

```php
$data = json_encode($contentPostData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json'                                                                       
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

If that does not work then most likely: a) your JSON is invalid (different structure is expected) or b) the webservice actually expects a different format than JSON (maybe standard multipart data for example)

Comment: Yes I am doing ```$data = json_encode($contentPostData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);```

Comment: also, I was already setting the Content-Type: application/json in the header before executing the cURL

Comment: Do you have any docs about expected input by that webservice?